# Ordenar linhas e colunas replicadas com angular

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Preciso de um auxílio para ordenar os botões que estou gerando com angular.
Estou utilizando o "ng-repeat" e está gerando os 8 botões corretamente porém eles estão ficando fora da ordem que necessito.
Segue o código e a imagem de saída:

```html
<style>
    .divpai {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 50%;
        border: 3px solid;
        border-color: darkblue;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .tclass {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    
    .tclass td {
        width: 513px;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    
    .btf {
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
</style>
<div class="page-header" id="principal" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
    <div class="divpai" style="width:950px; height: 734px; background-color:#F3E10A" align="center">
        <table class="tclass">
            <tr ng-repeat="menus in menu" style="text-align: right;">
                <td style="text-align: left;" ng-if="4>=($index+1)"><button id="btf1" class="btf" style="width:416px; height: 79px; background-color:#2E5491">{{menus.nome}}</button></td>
                <td style="text-align: right; " ng-if="($index+1)>=5"><button id="btf5" class="btf" style="width:416px; height: 79px; background-color:#2E5491">{{menus.nome}}</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: IMAGEM SAIDA ATUAL]

Desejo que apresente os botões de 1-4 no canto inferior esquerdo, e os botões de 5-8 no canto inferior direito.
Alguém tem idéia de como devo corrigir ?
Agradeço a toda e qualquer ajuda.

Comment: Na classe utilize [float;right] como propriedade css também.

Comment: Qual classe ? na segunda TD ?

Comment: Aplique nas classes dos elementos que você quer que fique na direita. Cuidado para não aplicar no ".btf" que irá aplicar à todos ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com [table](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table), a proposta seria outra, divida esse array em duas partes ou quantas partes forem necessárias (*vou seguir a linha da pergunta*) com o comando [slice](https://ariya.io/2014/02/javascript-array-slice-vs-splice) e coloque o [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) nos [button](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp) como exemplo abaixo:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.menu = [{
    'nome': 'Botão 1'
  }, {
    'nome': 'Botão 2'
  }, {
    'nome': 'Botão 3'
  }, {
    'nome': 'Botão 4'
  }, {
    'nome': 'Botão 5'
  }, {
    'nome': 'Botão 6'
  }, {
    'nome': 'Botão 7'
  }, {
    'nome': 'Botão 8'
  }, {
    'nome': 'Botão 9'
  }, {
    'nome': 'Botão 10'
  }];
  $scope.render = function(start, end) {
    return $scope.menu.slice(start, end);
  }
});
```

```css
.divpai {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  border: 3px solid;
  border-color: darkblue;
  position: relative;
}

.tclass {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.tclass td {
  width: 513px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.btf {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div class="page-header" id="principal" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
    <div class="divpai" style="width:100%; height: 734px; background-color:#F3E10A" align="center">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align: center;">
            <button id="btf1" ng-repeat="menus in render(0,5)" class="btf" style="width:100%; height: 79px; background-color:#2E5491">{{menus.nome}}</button>
          </td>
          <td style="text-align: center;">
            <button id="btf5" ng-repeat="menus in render(5,10)" class="btf" style="width:100%; height: 79px; background-color:#2E5491">{{menus.nome}}</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

dessa forma os 5 primeiros botões ficaram na primeira divisão da tabela e os outros 5 na segunda divisão da tabela.

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [JavaScript Array: slice vs splice](https://ariya.io/2014/02/javascript-array-slice-vs-splice)
- [Angular - ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)
- [HTML  Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp)
- [Table](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado. Fiz algumas adaptações e funcionou perfeitamente. Ainda estou estudando angular por isso sempre surge umas dúvidas bobas assim e mesmo pesquisando é muito subjetivo as soluções pra quando não se sabe.  Obrigado mais uma vez.